# Proving if $\lim|s_n|=0$ then $\limsup|s_n|=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, limsup-and-liminf, epsilon-delta

I am trying to prove that if $\lim|s_n|=0$ then $\limsup|s_n|=0$. My proof goes as follows:

Suppose $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n=0$, then this implies that $\forall \epsilon>0,\ \exists  N$ such that $ n>N$ implies $|s_n-0|< \epsilon $. This implies that $\epsilon$ is an upper bound for the set $\{|s_N|\ |n>N\}$.
Thus, we can conclude that $0<\sup\{|s_n|\ |n>N\}<\epsilon$ where we know the supremum is greater than $0$ because every term $|s_n|$ is greater than $0$. Thus, from this we can conclude that $\forall \epsilon>0,\ \exists  N$ such that $ n>N$ impliest that $|\sup\{|s_n|\ |n>N\}-0|< \epsilon $, and so we conclude that $\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\sup\{|s_n|\ |n>N\}=0$ $\rightarrow$ $\limsup|s_n|=0$.

Is this proof right? Thanks!

Comment: Your proof looks correct, except the inequality $0 < \sup\{|s_n| \mid n > N\}$ should be $0 \leq \sup\{|s_n| \mid n > N\}$ (you say that every term $|s_n|$ is greater than zero, but this is not clear from what you wrote). Have you heard of the more general result that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$, then $\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n = \liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$?

Comment: Thanks! I've heard of that result, but I was trying tor prove it in a different way.

Comment: You start your proof with assuming that $s_n$ converges to $0$. You should start it with assuming that $|s_n|$ converges to $0$.

Comment: "where we know the supremum is greater than $0$ because every term $|s_n|$ is greater than 0". We don't know that, from your hypotheses. We only know every term is $\ge 0$.

Comment: Your final conclusion would be more convincing, I think, if you use $\lim \sup_n |s_n| = \inf_N \sup_{n>N} |s_n| \le \sup_{n>N} |s_n| \le \epsilon$.

Comment: If $\lim x_n$ exists then $\lim \sup x_n = \lim x_n$.

Comment: @lhf Is that the definition of $\lim x_n$? Upon review, I think that is the definition if $x_n$'s are sets but not if they are numbers